# How to have a progress bar in jQuery.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

is it possible to have a progress bar measuring the jQuery.get() progress?

Comment: no AFAIK it is not possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not given out-of-the-box in the current version of jQuery, but still possible with little effort.

You should listen to the `progress` event of the `XMLHttpRequest` which jQuery gives you access to. An example [from Dave Bond's blog](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/):

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: 'POST', // 'POST' here so that _upload_ progress _also_ makes sense; 
                // Change to 'GET' if you need. 
  url: "/", data: {}, 
  beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    //Upload progress
    XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
      }
    }, false); 

    //Download progress
    XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
      }
    }, false); 
  },

  success: function(data){
    // successful completion handler
  }
});
```

Here the link to the [docs on `XMLHttpRequest`'s `progress` event](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress).

You may also want to take a look a the [jquery.ajax-progress plugin](http://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress) to avoid doing it yourself.

---

Notes:

- Some older browsers may not support the `progress` event.
- To calculate download progress, you must know the size of the resource to be downloaded, i.e. the server must send the `Content-length` HTTP header. If size is not known, then it's not possible to calculate the progress. This is what the `lengthComputable` property of the `progress` event is for.

Answer (score -3):

If you are able to divide up the task that the server is handling into chunks of processing you can make a servers response call another `$.get()` and update a progress bar that way.

```
function get_chunk(chunk_number, max_chunks){
    $.get('eg.php?chunk=' + chunk_number, function(){
        chunk_number++;
        if(chunk_number < max_chunks){
            get_chunk(chunk_number, max_chunks)
        }
        update_status_bar(chunk_number, max_chunks);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will have to look into a web application model like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) which uses server side pushing where the client does not have to make a request in order for data to be sent to the client

Comment: How so? if you can divide up the process that your server is doing into functions that can be called one after the other this can be done on most if not all technologies. It wouldnt work for things like retrieving an image necessarily without a bit of work, but if you need to return say a list of results from a database you could limit the results from the database and pull back 100 at a time rather than the whole result set of say 100000

Comment: Well.. How are you going to determine which file is downloaded by which user? Session? Php uses session lock so that the session file can only be use by one request at any one time..

Comment: There will only ever be one request at any one time. When one request ends the next one begins

Comment: Ahh ic.. my bad. I misunderstood your solution.

Comment: This is a terrible solution, there's a reason XHR progress events exist.

Comment: It may not be the most elegant solution but as Alex said in his answer the progress event doesn't exist in older browsers. By the looks of it that includes IE8 and 9